# Extract key-value pairs from single html paragraph

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to extract key-value pairs from an html file (see example below). Unfortunately, there is no html node that corresponds to each key-value pair (such as a div element). Instead, all information comes in a single paragraph where keys are highlighted as `<strong>`.

I would like to present the key-value pairs as two columns of a dataframe or two same-length lists where `key 1` corresponds to `value 1`, `key 2` to `value 2a` and `value 2b`, and `key 3` to `value 3`. Line breaks are not set consistently in the file.

Since there are no div elements for each pair, I would probably have to come up with a strategy to *split* the paragraph after each key? I attach a hacky attempt below that treats html as raw text:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

html <- minimal_html(
  "<p>
    <strong>key 1</strong> value 1
    <br></br>
    <strong>key 2</strong> value 2a
    <br></br>
    value 2b
    <br></br>
    <strong>key 3</strong> 
    <br></br>
    value 3
  </p>"
)

# hacky solution treating html as raw text
s <- html |> 
  html_elements("p") |> 
  as.character()

parse_html <- function(s) {
  s |> 
    read_html() |> 
    html_text2()
}

s |> 
  str_replace_all("<strong>(.*)</strong>", "✂️\\1") |> 
  str_split_1("✂️") |> 
  map_chr(parse_html) |> 
  discard(\(x) str_length(x) == 0L) |> 
  str_split("") |> 
  map(str_squish)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "key 1"   "value 1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "key 2"             "value 2a value 2b"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "key 3"   "value 3"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath we can get a bit further than with CSS selectors, while the example bellow seems to handle that included html snippet, I'm sure there are way more robust and elegant XPath strategies to achieve that same goal.

We can start from *values*, with `.//p/strong/following-sibling::text()` we can get all text nodes (*values*) that follow `strong` elements, whitespace-only strings are fine as we can filter those out later. While iterating through that node-set, we can now get the closest preceding `strong` element (*key*) for every text node with `./preceding-sibling::strong[1]` .

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

html <- minimal_html(
  "<p>
    <strong>key 1</strong> value 1
    <br></br>
    <strong>key 2</strong> value 2a
    <br></br>
    value 2b
    <br></br>
    <strong>key 3</strong> 
    <br></br>
    value 3
  </p>"
)

preceding_key_text <- function(value_node){
  html_element(value_node, xpath = "./preceding-sibling::strong[1]") |> 
    html_text(trim = TRUE)
}

html |>
  html_elements(xpath = ".//p/strong/following-sibling::text()") |> 
  map(\(value_) list(
    key = preceding_key_text(value_),
    value = html_text(value_, trim = TRUE)
    )) |>
  discard(\(x) x[["value"]] == "") |>
  bind_rows()
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   key   value   
#>   <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 key 1 value 1 
#> 2 key 2 value 2a
#> 3 key 2 value 2b
#> 4 key 3 value 3
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Amazing! I am starting to appreciate the flexibility of xpath syntax. Interesting that the text containing the value is considered a sibling even though it is not wrapped in its own `<p>` tag. Do you perhaps have any pointers to resources on how to use xpath for webscraping purposes? Thanks!

Comment: No, nothing specific, sorry, but I would not limit XPath resources to (just) web and scraping topics. I've learned to appreciate `text()` and have an intuition on what might be possible, but I'm mostly trying to avoid XPath and most of more advanced XPath examples you could find when browsing through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath?tab=Votes are over my head.  Though checking `xml2::html_structure(html)`can be useful, just to identify accessible entities.  As well as "copy XPath" in Chrome object inspector to get some crude baseline expression that can be then tweaked.